# Timeout when communicating with Web3 Provider

Tags: node.js, docker, nft, avalanche

**Background**

I am trying to investigate and solve problems with a containerized NodeJS web service app that communicates with Avalanche Test Network (https://api.avax-test.network/ext/bc/C/rpc) in order to Mint NFTs.

```
//...
provider = new HDWalletProvider({
    privateKeys: [walletPrivateKey],
    providerOrUrl: "https://api.avax-test.network/ext/bc/C/rpc",
    pollingInterval: 4000,
});

const myContract = Contract(Contract_NFT);
myContract.setProvider(provider);

const _instance = await myContract.at(process.env.CONTRACT_NFT_ADDRESS);

_instance.mint(provider.getAddress(), mintURL, { from: provider.getAddress() })
//...
```

Note: I am not the developer of app.

**Issue**

After starting the container, first request completes successfully. However subsequent requests fail with `code: -32603 message: 'ETIMEDOUT'` error

```
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
at Web3ProviderEngine.emit (node:events:502:17)
at /app/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:54:14
at afterRequest (/app/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:148:21)
at /app/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:174:21
at /app/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:232:9
at /app/node_modules/async/internal/once.js:12:16
at replenish (/app/node_modules/async/internal/eachOfLimit.js:61:25)
at /app/node_modules/async/internal/eachOfLimit.js:71:9
at eachLimit (/app/node_modules/async/eachLimit.js:43:36)
at /app/node_modules/async/internal/doLimit.js:9:16
at end (/app/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:211:5)
at Request._callback (/app/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc.js:36:21)
at self.callback (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
at Request.emit (node:events:513:28)
at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:851:16)

Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
undefined
    at PollingBlockTracker._performSync (/app/node_modules/eth-block-tracker/src/polling.js:51:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

When the app is used outside a container and directly on server OS, all requests successfully complete.

**What I have tried**

I tried searching the internet forums and boards. Similar issue is mentioned in some posts but suggested solution is to tweak Timeout/Interval values which did not help with my issue and still got the error.

I tried using the same NodeJS and NPM versions installed on server OS. Also tried using different versions of NodeJS( 14.XX, 16.XX). Still got the same error.

Also I have tried changing and configuring Docker network( different type of network driver, different IPAM config, passing extra hosts etc.). Still got the same error.

I have confirmed that mentioned URL is accessible from inside container using `ping`, `nc` and `dig` tools. Also have confirmed that successful HTTPS connection is being established.

**Questions**

What is causing this behavior?

What I can do to reliably use this app inside container?

Have I missed something?